# Does my truck slow down when there are zombies on it?

Tags: zombie-highway-2

In Zombie Highway 2, the idea is that you kill zombies that hang on the side of your truck. Apart from the chance to flip over, are there any more downsides to let the zombies hang longer? I can shoot them to make them disappear as fast as possible, but I will run out of bullets. For example of downsides: do they slow down the truck?

Comment: In the first game, the longer they hung on, the more they moved you off-course when they shook your vehicle.  Also, if there were more than one, they tended to move you in different frequencies so that they would coincide and be impossible to compensate for.  This inevitably led to a crash if you didn't scrape them off (or, in case of emergency, ventilate their heads) quickly.

Comment: @gatherer818 I will try to pay attention if this also happens in the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Zombies do not slow down your vehicle. The only things that can do that are driving in the dirt (off of the road) and crashing into barricades and cars. They will however, begin to tip over the car, especially if it is one of the faster, lighter cars. This applies to both games.